# Where can I find the nameSpace System.Net.Mail (or similar) in .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, email

I need to program a functionality in .Net for sending mails. After some reading, I found that the classes from System.Net.Mail may be useful. Yet... I can't find that namespace nor any suitable import to access these classes.

Can anyone point out some solution to me?

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a reference to `System.dll`, it should be fine - although looking at the documentation for some classes it looks like for the *client* profile of .NET 3.5, it was only introduced in .NET 3.5 SP1.

So you either need the full desktop framework, or make sure that if you're using the client profile that you've got 3.5 SP1.